# get a list of comments with answers

Tags: arrays, database, typescript, list, typeorm

I have comments on article. But I decided to expand the possibilities of commenting a little, added the ability to reply to a comment.

Comment entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Comment {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50 })
  content: string;

  @Column()
  authorId: string;

  @Column()
  entityId: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  creatAt: Date;

  @Column('text', { nullable: true })
  replyId?: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: CommentTypeEnum })
  type: CommentTypeEnum;
}
```

A bit of specifics:
When I create a reply to a comment, I get the id of the parent's comment (the comment I reply to) and write it to the replyId. The parent can have NULL or also contain an id. Simply put, a new comment contains the id of its parent.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "dee96b97-cd45-4a09-a27d-985617cc5a16",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:35.204Z",
    "replyId": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  },
  {
    "id": "d61e0049-9075-4f25-8f6d-65ed61e245a8",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:21.271Z",
    "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  },
  {
    "id": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.663Z",
    "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  },
  {
    "id": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:04.391Z",
    "replyId": null,
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  },
  {
    "id": "1ea5cdcb-2f19-4b00-94e0-5b245bb91237",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.094Z",
    "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  }
]
```

Method by which I get all the records for a particular record:

```
@Get('/:entityId/comments')
  async getAll(@Param('entityId') entityId: string): Promise<CommentDto[]> {
    const comments = await this.commentRepository.find({ where: { entityId: entityId }, order: { id: 'DESC' } });
    return comments.map(it => ({
      id: it.id,
      content: it.content,
      authorId: it.authorId,
      entityId: it.entityId,
      creatAt: it.creatAt,
      replyId: it.replyId || null,
      type: it.type,
    }));
  }
```

DTO:

```
export class CommentDto {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  authorId: string;
  entityId: string;
  creatAt: Date;
  replyId?: string;
  type: CommentTypeEnum;
}
```

How to get records like in the example below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:04.391Z",
    "replyId": [
        {
          "id": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.663Z",
          "replyId": [
              {
                "id": "dee96b97-cd45-4a09-a27d-985617cc5a16",
                "content": "comment",
                "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
                "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
                "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:35.204Z",
                "replyId": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
                "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
              }
            ],
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        },
        {
          "id": "d61e0049-9075-4f25-8f6d-65ed61e245a8",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:21.271Z",
          "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        },
        {
          "id": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.663Z",
          "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ea5cdcb-2f19-4b00-94e0-5b245bb91237",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.094Z",
          "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        }
      ],
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Look up "many to one" relations for TypeOrm
(https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations).

Effectively, you want:

```
@ManyToOne(type => Comment)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'replyId' })
reply?: Comment | null;

@Column({ nullable: true })
@Index()
replyId: string | null;
```

And then use:

```
await this.commentRepository.find({
    where: { entityId: entityId },
    relations: ['reply'],
    order: { id: 'DESC' }
});
```

Quick warning, typeorm will not by default fetch all relations to unlimited depth. `relations: ['reply']` will go one depth. `relations: ['reply', 'reply.reply', 'reply.reply.reply']` will go up to 3 (but get slower and slower the higher you go).